# Chrome: Cursor moves to end of input form after pressing backspace key

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, input

I've noticed some weird behaviour lately when using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57 m. (untested on other browsers) When typing into a form field, most commonly a text area field, if I attempt to use the backspace key in the middle of the content, it deletes the character as expected, but then instantly jumps to the end of the content.

This has been irritating to say the least since I usually hit the backspace key several times to delete multiple characters, only to end up deleting the characters at the end of what I've typed. Has anyone else experienced this? If so, are there any known fixes or at least an explanation? Thank you!

Side note: I have no extensions installed, third party or otherwise, but did try activating the "auto-correct" feature outlined [here.](http://www.geek.com/apps/google-chrome-is-getting-autocorrect-1551686/) I have since disabled the auto-correct, but the issue persists.